# how to send array in props(reactjs)?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react I need to pass array to another `component` via `props` but i got an issue

**in Component1**

```
this.state={
   data:[], //some values inside both it
   col:[]
    }

<Component2 data={[...this.state.data]} col={[...this.state.col]}/>
```

**in Component2**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        data:[...this.props.data],
        col:[...this.props.col],

    }
    console.log(this.state.data+' inside state')
}
```

when I `console.log` i get the below output

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object] inside state

one of my array has 17 elements but why am not getting the actual data?is there any syntax error in my code?

Comment: `one of my array has 17 elements but why am not getting the actual data?` What do you mean, your question shows it logs the data. Maybe try: `console.log(this.state.data,' inside state'`)`. I'm also not sure why you want copy data that is passed to Component2 to local state and why you make a shallow copy of the data twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of your components, you should not have to use [the extract/destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Instead just assign the values as they are.

### Example:

#### Component 1

```
this.state={
   data:[], //some values inside both it
   col:[]
}

<Component2 data={this.state.data} col={this.state.col}/>
```

#### Component 2

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        data: this.props.data,
        col: this.props.col,

    }
    // Also you were casting to a string here, just pass the data as second parameter to log it.
    console.log('inside state', this.state.data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
com 1:

     <Component2 data={this.state.data} col={this.state.col} />

com 2: 

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data:this.props.data,
            col:this.props.col,

        }
        console.log(this.state.data + ' inside state');
        console.log(this.state.col + ' inside state');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

React documentation explicitly states of not setting state from props, instead use the props directly. That is what they are for.